# Inspecting every packet leaving the system for sensitive information ?

Tags: network, firewalls

Is there a way to check *every* packet leaving the system for sensitive data like IP addresses, personal information (like logins) etc ?

A free (and preferably open source) program which does this for Linux would be great.

Otherwise, where would I start to go about coding something like this ?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're asking for something that will do this for a single computer you control, or for an entire network?

Comment: Are you concerned about accidental leaks or about malicious leaks? These are completely different scenarios.

Comment: @Xander for a single computer.

Comment: @Gilles Accidental leaks being the data transmitted by email clients, chat software etc ? then yes, its intended for that.

Comment: Accidental as in an employee accidentally sends the customer list to joe@competitor.com instead of joe@yourcompany.com. Deliberate as in a disgruntled employee sends the customer list on wilileaks.org over a VPN that they installed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [network data loss prevention](http://www.codegreennetworks.com/products/network-data-loss-prevention/).

There are some costly solutions from Code Green Networks, Symantec, etc.  One free and GNU GPL-licensed ones is [MyDLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyDLP) (specifically you'll want the MyDLP-Network product) that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wireshark for sniffing packets and getting every kind of information from that.

Wireshark is opensource project 
Check out its official page: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Poor man's version of that network sniffer is at http://www.tcpdump.org/